# Decrypting text with same key, gives Invalid Token

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I can encrypt with key `key1` which comes from a specific file, but I cannot decrypt the file with the same key, it gives me `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken` even when it is the same key from the same file `Securi1.key` and read in as `rb`

```
# This function calls the pre-existing key to encrypt and decrypt files
def securi1_key():
    file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi1.key", 'rb')
    global key1
    key1 = file.read()
    file.close()

# this code encrypts the documents text and then replaces the raw text with encrypted string
def rewrite_yellow():
    securi1_key()
    save_yellow_text() #existing text
    #   get key from file
    file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi1.key", 'rb')
    texty = scan4yellow.decode("utf-8")
    encodedy = texty.encode()

    #   encrypt message
    f = Fernet(key1)
    encryptedy = f.encrypt(encodedy)
    # replaces document text with encrypted text
    document = docx.Document(f1)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in paragraph.text:
            inline = paragraph.runs
            # loops for runs
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in inline[i].text:
                    text = inline[i].text.replace(scan4yellow.decode("utf-8"), encryptedy.decode("utf-8"))
                    inline[i].text = text
    document.save(f1)

#this function should ideally decrypt
def decrypt_yellow():
    securi1_key()
    inputfile = (f1)
    list_of_inputfiles = os.listdir("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/")

    with open(inputfile, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()

    file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi1.key", "rb")
    global key1
    key1 = file.read()
    file.close()

    f2 = Fernet(key1) # <-- key1 is from Securi1 so it should decrypt
    decryptedy = decryptedy = f2.decrypt(data) #encrypted contains OG text so it decrypts it with the key
    # replaces the text
    document = docx.Document(f1)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in paragraph.text:
            inline = paragraph.runs
            #loops for the runs
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in inline[i].text:
                    text = inline[i].text.replace(scan4yellow.decode("utf-8"), decryptedy.decode("utf-8"))
                    inline[i].text = text
    document.save(f1)
    inputfile.close()
    os.remove(inputfile)
```

It should decrypt the text and then replace the encrypted text with the OG text which is in the encrypted file which wont decrypt

Comment: Can you please edit and include the exact traceback? Also, a copy of the key file would be useful. Will do my best to help with this.

Comment: Another thing to add would be that `InvalidToken` is raised when the ciphertext is corrupt.